# Prove that a function is smooth easily

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, smooth-functions

In [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2978532/4876) I claimed that the function $f (x) = x^{n + 1} \sin \exp \frac{1}{x}$ is smooth in all points except zero.

But how to prove this claim easily (without calculating the derivative explicitly)?

I want a short proof that $f$ is smooth in non-zero points.

Comment: Products and compositions of differentiable functions are differentiable.

Comment: @Sobi Oh, I see: all functions in consideration are smooth in all points except of $\frac1x$ smooth everywhere except of zero. It was easy, I should have not asked this question

Comment: Well, the function in question is even differentiable in zero if $n>0$, provided you define $f(0)=0$.